# Code optimization in django

Tags: python, django

In views.py I have 2 views, all of them have both functions:

```
def A():
    some code..
    def my_def:
        some code

def B():
     some code..
     def my_def:
        some code
```

I tryed to define my_def as a A or B:

```
def my_def():
    some code

def A():
    some code
    var = my_def()

def B():
    some code
    var = my_def()
```

But it doesnt work. How to fix this? Thanks

Comment: When you say "it doesn't work", what's the exact text of the error message you get?

Comment: Posting your actual code and the error will enable us to provide a better response.

Comment: Especially when the supplied code doesn't know if it's JavaScript, Python or something else.

Comment: This is called code refactoring, which is not really code optimization.

Comment: What's the error you are facing? Can you post the Traceback?